# CSS Margin not working in React typescript project

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass

CSS margin not working in my react typescript project

My code:

```
const Home: React.FC = () => {
return (
<div style={{ width: "100vw", background: "skyblue" }}>
  <div
    style={{
      background: "red",
      height: "100px",
      width: "100px",
      marginLeft: "100px",
    }}
  ></div>
</div>
);
};
```

[Codesandbox link for this project](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-ives-rx48z?file=/src/pages/home.tsx:115-428)

Comment: Check your https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-ives-rx48z?file=/src/App.css file. Margin is being applied to all elements with `!important` which is not good.

Comment: Because you override this style in your `App.css` with a `* { margin: 0px !important;}`.

Comment: Okay, thanks! don't know how I missed that @m4n0

Comment: @Hadiazeez you should use chrome inspector tool to figure out what styles are getting applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your margin is overridden by `margin: 0px !important` which is declared in your `App.css` file